# Want to display 1 column values multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using ORACLE 11g. I have table like this

```
col1     col2
john      1
david     2
root      3
baily     4
```

I want output like below table to print 1 row multiple times

```
col1     col2
john      1
david     2
david     2
root      3
root      3
root      3
baily     4
baily     4
baily     4
baily     4
```

Comment: "SQL 11g" does not exist. You are most likely using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Are the values in `col1` in your input table distinct (unique)? If they are, it would be helpful to mention that. If they aren't, it's not 100% clear what the desired output is. For example, suppose the input consists of exactly two rows, both with the values `john, 3`. What is the desired output in that case?

Answer (score 2):

I have assumed you are using Oracle 11g (i.e. the SQL syntax below is for Oracle)

Joining your data to a "numbers table" will repeat each row according to the value in col2. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   col1 VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,col2 INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2) VALUES ('john',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2) VALUES ('david',2);
INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2) VALUES ('root',3);
INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2) VALUES ('baily',4);


select col1, col2
from mytable t
inner join (
   select 1 as n from dual union all
   select 2 as n from dual union all
   select 3 as n from dual union all
   select 4 as n from dual
   ) n on t.col2 >= n.n
   order by col2, col1


+-------+------+
| COL1  | COL2 |
+-------+------+
| john  |    1 |
| david |    2 |
| david |    2 |
| root  |    3 |
| root  |    3 |
| root  |    3 |
| baily |    4 |
| baily |    4 |
| baily |    4 |
| baily |    4 |
+-------+------+
```

nb: It is possible to form the needed "numbers table" several different ways.

e.g. use any existing table with sufficient rows in it for your purpose

```
select row_number() over(order by table_name) as n
from all_tables
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5153fb097bab33a353e67bd10ba19a97)

Comment: `n.n` will probably work, but doesn't seem like a good idea. Best to use a different name/alias for the view and for the column.

Answer (score 0):

With sample data you posted

```
SQL> select * From test order by col2;

COL1        COL2
----- ----------
john           1
david          2
root           3
baily          4
```

query that returns desired result might be

```
SQL> select col1, col2
  2  from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  3                                           connect by level <= col2
  4                                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  5  order by col2;

COL1        COL2
----- ----------
john           1
david          2
david          2
root           3
root           3
root           3
baily          4
baily          4
baily          4
baily          4

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query presuming the name values(`col1`) are unique throughout the table such as

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM t
CONNECT BY level <= col2   
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR col1 = col1
  ORDER BY col2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dd9232b80f309f9edc1b945f525556e3)</kbd>